# CUDA performance with Computer Vision Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, performance, opencv, cuda

I'm moving my first step in the CUDA C programming world!

As first test I write simple algorithm to do gray conversion and thresholding on images (I am a fan of Computer Vision and OpenCV!).
I decided to compare my CUDA performance result with an analogous algorithm on the CPU and with the corresponding OpenCV (cpu) functions. 
Here the result on a full hd video:

```
Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
Total time CPU: 67418.6 ms
Frame Avg CPU:  14.1814 ms

Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
Total time OpenCV: 23805.3 ms
Frame Avg OpenCV:  5.00742 ms

Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
==6149== NVPROF is profiling process 6149, command: ./OpenCV_test
Total time CUDA: 28018.2 ms
Frame Avg CUDA:  5.89361 ms

==6149== Profiling application: ./OpenCV_test
==6149== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
55.45%  4.05731s      4754  853.45us  849.54us  1.1141ms doThreshold(unsigned char const *, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
34.03%  2.49028s      4754  523.83us  513.67us  1.3338ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
10.52%  769.46ms      4754  161.85us  161.15us  301.06us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]

==6149== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 80.11%  8.19501s      9508  861.91us  490.81us  2.7719ms  cudaMemcpy
 12.82%  1.31106s      9508  137.89us  66.639us  218.56ms  cudaMalloc
  5.74%  587.05ms      9508  61.742us  39.566us  2.0234ms  cudaFree
  1.21%  124.16ms      4754  26.116us  16.990us  365.86us  cudaLaunch
  0.06%  5.7645ms     23770     242ns      97ns  106.27us  cudaSetupArgument
  0.05%  5.4291ms      4754  1.1410us     602ns  10.150us  cudaConfigureCall
  0.01%  594.89us        83  7.1670us     249ns  282.44us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.00%  45.536us         1  45.536us  45.536us  45.536us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.00%  35.649us         1  35.649us  35.649us  35.649us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.00%  1.8960us         2     948ns     345ns  1.5510us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%     892ns         2     446ns     255ns     637ns  cuDeviceGet
```

As you can see OpenCV does much better than my cpu implementation and better than my Cuda algorithm! Where is the trick? My suspect is than OpenCV uses some special cpu hardware instruction set.
I expected something more with CUDA: people talk about speedup of 20x-30x in primitive image processing! I missed something?

Here some detail about my system configuration:

- Cpu Intel Core i7 5820k @4ghz
- GeForce GTX 970
- Linux Mint 17.2 Mate 64 bit
- Driver nVidia 352.55
- Cuda toolkit 7.5.18

Here some information on my OpenCV 3.0 build:

- Cuda enabled
- OpenCL disabled
- TBB disabled (to try to force single thread cpu execution)
- Intel IPP enabled

In the following the code executed for the test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

const char* file = "PATH TO A VIDEO FILE";

__global__ void doThreshold(const uchar* bgrInput, uchar* output, uint inputSize, uint soglia, uint maxVal)
{
    uint i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < inputSize)
    {
        output[i] = 0.5f + ((bgrInput[3 * i] + bgrInput[3 * i + 1] + bgrInput[3 * i + 2]) / 3.0f); // gray conversion
        output[i] = output[i] > soglia ? maxVal : 0; // thresholding
    }

}


void cudaCvtThreshold(const Mat& mat, Mat& result, uint soglia, uint maxVal)
{
    if (mat.type() == CV_8UC3)
    {
        uint size = mat.rows * mat.cols;
        uint blockSize = 128; // no significant result varying this variable
        uint gridSize = ceil(size/(float)blockSize);
        uchar* d_bgrInput, *d_output;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_bgrInput, mat.channels() * size);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_output, size);
        cudaMemcpy(d_bgrInput, mat.data, mat.channels() * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        doThreshold<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_bgrInput, d_output, size, soglia, maxVal);

        result = Mat(mat.rows, mat.cols, CV_8UC1);
        cudaMemcpy(result.data, d_output, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaFree(d_bgrInput);
        cudaFree(d_output);
    }
    else
        cerr << "Only CV_8UC3 matrix supported" << endl;

}

void cpuCvtThreshold(const Mat& mat, Mat& result, uint soglia, uint maxVal)
{
    if (mat.type() == CV_8UC3)
    {
        uint size = mat.rows * mat.cols;
        result = Mat(mat.rows, mat.cols, CV_8UC1);
        uchar* input = mat.data;
        uchar* output = result.data;
        for (uint i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            output[i] = 0.5f + ((input[3 * i] + input[3 * i + 1] + input[3 * i + 2]) / 3.0f); // gray conversion
            output[i] = output[i] > soglia ? maxVal : 0; // thresholding
        }
    }
    else
        cerr << "Only CV_8UC3 matrix supported" << endl;
}

void cudaTest(const string src)
{
    VideoCapture cap(src);
    Mat frame, result;
    uint frameCount = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    cout << "Frame Count: " << frameCount << endl;
    auto startTs = system_clock::now();
    cap >> frame;
    cout << "Frame Resolution: " << frame.cols << "x" << frame.rows << endl;

    while (not frame.empty()) {
        cudaCvtThreshold(frame, result, 127, 255);
        cap >> frame;
    }

    auto stopTs = system_clock::now();
    auto diff = stopTs - startTs;
    auto elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(diff).count() / (double)1e3;
    cout << "Total time CUDA: " << elapsed << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Frame Avg CUDA:  " << elapsed / frameCount << " ms" << endl << endl;
}

void naiveCpu(const string src)
{
    VideoCapture cap(src);
    Mat frame, result;
    uint frameCount = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    cout << "Frame Count: " << frameCount << endl;
    auto startTs = system_clock::now();
    cap >> frame;
    cout << "Frame Resolution: " << frame.cols << "x" << frame.rows << endl;

    while (not frame.empty()) {
        cpuCvtThreshold(frame, result, 127, 255);
        cap >> frame;
    }
    auto stopTs = system_clock::now();
    auto diff = stopTs - startTs;
    auto elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(diff).count() / (double)1e3;
    cout << "Total time CPU: " << elapsed << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Frame Avg CPU:  " << elapsed / frameCount << " ms" << endl << endl;
}


void opencv(const string src)
{
    VideoCapture cap(src);
    Mat frame, result;
    uint frameCount = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    cout << "Frame Count: " << frameCount << endl;
    auto startTs = system_clock::now();
    cap >> frame;
    cout << "Frame Resolution: " << frame.cols << "x" << frame.rows << endl;

    while (not frame.empty()) {
        cv::cvtColor(frame, result, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        threshold(result, result, 127, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
        cap >> frame;
    }
    auto stopTs = system_clock::now();
    auto diff = stopTs - startTs;
    auto elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(diff).count() / (double)1e3;
    cout << "Total time OpenCV: " << elapsed << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Frame Avg OpenCV:  " << elapsed / frameCount << " ms" << endl << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    naiveCpu(file);
    opencv(file);
    cudaTest(file);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Added / modified code

```
__global__ void doThreshold(const uchar* bgrInput, uchar* output, uint inputSize, uint soglia, uint maxVal)
{
    uint i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < inputSize)
    {
        uchar grayPix = 0.5f + ((bgrInput[3 * i] + bgrInput[3 * i + 1] + bgrInput[3 * i + 2]) / 3.0f); // gray conversion
        output[i] = grayPix > soglia ? maxVal : 0; // thresholding
    }

}

void cudaCvtThreshold(const Mat& mat, Mat& result, uint soglia, uint maxVal, uchar* d_bgrInput, uchar* d_output)
{
    uint size = mat.rows * mat.cols;
    uint blockSize = 128; // no significant result varying this variable
    uint gridSize = ceil(size/(float)blockSize);
    doThreshold<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_bgrInput, d_output, size, soglia, maxVal);
}

void cudaTestOutMallocFree(const string src)
{
    VideoCapture cap(src);
    Mat frame;
    uint frameCount = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    cout << "Frame Count: " << frameCount << endl;
    auto startTs = system_clock::now();
    cap >> frame;
    cout << "Frame Resolution: " << frame.cols << "x" << frame.rows << endl;
    uint size = frame.rows * frame.cols;

    Mat result(frame.rows, frame.cols, CV_8UC1);
    uchar* d_bgrInput, *d_output;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_bgrInput, frame.channels() * size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_output, size);

    while (not frame.empty())
    {
        cudaMemcpy(d_bgrInput, frame.data, frame.channels() * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaCvtThreshold(frame, result, 127, 255, d_bgrInput, d_output);
        cudaMemcpy(result.data, d_output, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cap >> frame;
    }

    cudaFree(d_bgrInput);
    cudaFree(d_output);

    auto stopTs = system_clock::now();
    auto diff = stopTs - startTs;
    auto elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(diff).count() / (double)1e3;
    cout << "Total time CUDA (out malloc-free): " << elapsed << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Frame Avg CUDA (out malloc-free):  " << elapsed / frameCount << " ms" << endl << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    naiveCpu(file);
    opencv(file);
    cudaTest(file);
    cudaTestOutMallocFree(file);
    return 0;
}
```

And results:

```
Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
Total time CPU: 70972.6 ms
Frame Avg CPU:  14.929 ms

Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
Total time OpenCV: 23475.4 ms
Frame Avg OpenCV:  4.93804 ms

Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
==4493== NVPROF is profiling process 4493, command: ./OpenCV_test
Total time CUDA: 27451.3 ms
Frame Avg CUDA:  5.77435 ms

Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
Total time CUDA (out malloc-free): 26137.3 ms
Frame Avg CUDA (out malloc-free):  5.49796 ms

==4493== Profiling application: ./OpenCV_test
==4493== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 53.74%  7.53280s      9508  792.26us  789.61us  896.17us  doThreshold(unsigned char const *, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
 35.57%  4.98604s      9508  524.40us  513.54us  979.37us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
 10.69%  1.49876s      9508  157.63us  157.09us  206.24us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]

==4493== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 88.22%  15.7392s     19016  827.68us  482.18us  1.7570ms  cudaMemcpy
  7.07%  1.26081s      9510  132.58us  65.458us  198.86ms  cudaMalloc
  3.26%  582.24ms      9510  61.223us  39.675us  304.16us  cudaFree
  1.33%  236.64ms      9508  24.888us  13.497us  277.21us  cudaLaunch
  0.06%  10.667ms     47540     224ns      96ns  347.09us  cudaSetupArgument
  0.06%  9.9587ms      9508  1.0470us     504ns  9.4800us  cudaConfigureCall
  0.00%  428.88us        83  5.1670us     225ns  228.70us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.00%  43.388us         1  43.388us  43.388us  43.388us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.00%  34.389us         1  34.389us  34.389us  34.389us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.00%  1.7010us         2     850ns     409ns  1.2920us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%     821ns         2     410ns     225ns     596ns  cuDeviceGet
```

Better performances with single malloc and free, but small improvement...

EDIT2:

As suggested by Jez I modified the Cuda Kernel in order to process multiple pixel (8 in the following execution) inside each GPU thread:

Here the modified code:

```
__global__ void doThreshold(const uchar* bgrInput, uchar* output, uint inputSize, uint soglia, uint maxVal, uint pixelPerThread)
{
    uint i = pixelPerThread * (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);

    if (i < inputSize)
    {
        for (uint j = 0; j < pixelPerThread; j++) {
            uchar grayPix = 0.5f + ( (bgrInput[3 * (i + j)] + bgrInput[3 * (i + j) + 1] + bgrInput[3 * (i + j) + 2]) / 3.0f ); // gray conversion
            output[i + j] = grayPix > soglia ? maxVal : 0; // thresholding
        }
    }
}

void cudaCvtThreshold(const Mat& mat, Mat& result, uint soglia, uint maxVal, uchar* d_bgrInput, uchar* d_output)
{
    uint size = mat.rows * mat.cols;
    uint pixelPerThread = 8;
    uint blockSize = 128; // no significant result varying this variable
    uint gridSize = ceil(size/(float)(blockSize * pixelPerThread));
    doThreshold<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_bgrInput, d_output, size, soglia, maxVal, pixelPerThread);
}
```

Then the results:

```
Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
Total time OpenCV: 23628.8 ms
Frame Avg OpenCV:  4.97031 ms

Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
==13441== NVPROF is profiling process 13441, command: ./OpenCV_test
Total time CUDA (out malloc-free): 25655.5 ms
Frame Avg CUDA (out malloc-free):  5.39662 ms

==13441== Profiling application: ./OpenCV_test
==13441== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 49.30%  3.15853s      4754  664.39us  658.24us  779.04us  doThreshold(unsigned char const *, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
 38.69%  2.47838s      4754  521.32us  513.35us  870.69us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
 12.01%  769.53ms      4754  161.87us  161.31us  200.58us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]

==13441== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 95.78%  7.26387s      9508  763.97us  491.11us  1.6589ms  cudaMemcpy
  2.51%  190.70ms         2  95.350ms  82.529us  190.62ms  cudaMalloc
  1.53%  116.31ms      4754  24.465us  16.844us  286.56us  cudaLaunch
  0.09%  6.7052ms     28524     235ns      98ns  233.19us  cudaSetupArgument
  0.08%  5.9538ms      4754  1.2520us     642ns  12.039us  cudaConfigureCall
  0.00%  263.87us        83  3.1790us     225ns  111.03us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.00%  174.45us         2  87.227us  52.521us  121.93us  cudaFree
  0.00%  34.612us         1  34.612us  34.612us  34.612us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.00%  29.376us         1  29.376us  29.376us  29.376us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.00%  1.6950us         2     847ns     343ns  1.3520us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%     745ns         2     372ns     217ns     528ns  cuDeviceGet
```

Notice that the average time for the kernel execution is now 664,39 us instead of 792,26 us
Not bad! :-)
But OpenCV (using Intel IPP) is still faster!

EDIT3:
I recompiled OpenCV WITHOUT IPP and the various SSE instructions. The OpenCV performances seem to be the same!!

```
Frame Count: 4754
Frame Resolution: 1920x1080
Total time OpenCV: 23541.7 ms
Frame Avg OpenCV:  4.95198 ms
```

Comment: The first optimization you can do is to remove the redundant memory allocations and deletions inside `cudaCvtThreshold`. Just do a single device memory allocation in the `cudaTest` function and use it for subsequent `cudaCvtThreshold` calls. Also, opencv uses CPU vector instructions like SSE, SSE2, AVX etc inside its primitives which is one of the reason for its speed.

Comment: Inside the kernel, you may use a register to store the result of grayscale conversion, and then threshold that value so that now global memory would have to be written only once, reducing the overhead of 1 global read and 1 global write. (Although the gpu may cache the memory access, but it is still worth a try)

Comment: The compiler will avoid the intermediate write/read from global in this case. Still, that's good advice given the compiler can't always do this, especially if aliasing information isn't given,

Comment: The short answer is that both CPU and CUDA code are poor. As I understand, you expect that naive CPU implementation would be slow. And for CUDA, you cannot just move the code in the kernel and expect it will magically work faster. Parallel programming requires completely different thinking, data layouts and patterns. Not even mentioning your malloc and kernel launches inside the loop.

Comment: @sgarizvi: I made the decision to do malloc and free inside the function cudaCvtThreshold in order to have a function ready to be used directly with Mat objects. However I will post the same test with external malloc and free. I will do also one memory access in the Cuda kernel but I don't think this can cause a significant performance penalty.

Comment: @drop: the CPU code is voluntarily naive. For the Cuda Kernel honestly I don't know how to write more efficient code. At most I can save a memory access as sgarizvi suggests...

Comment: I edited my question adding the results with the modified code (single malloc and free)

Comment: Huh, looks like I was wrong about working through a tmp. Odd.

Comment: @drakon I've already answered with some suggestions regarding writing more efficient code...

Comment: In addition to @Jez answer, I would also suggest this other answer to figure out if your problem, or parts of  it, is suitable for parallelization. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17484085/2064818

Comment: @drakon A good starting point would be ["Best practices" section in CUDA docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/) (it's almost entirely about runtime performance). Also, there are plenty of books and online material if you are interested in high-performance coding. As you have a reference OpenCV implementation you do your comparison against, a good idea would be to download it's source code, review it and try to achieve same result or even better (and in that case to contribute it back into OpenCV repository ;) )

Comment: Updated benchmarks with multiple pixels computation inside each gpu thread! Another step forward! :-)

Comment: You really should be looking into shared memory.

Comment: Updated with OpenCV without IPP and SSE. No significant changes... :-(

Comment: @Jez: sorry but I don't understand what you intend for "shared memory". Maybe are you talking about memory shared by all the GPU threads inside a single block? If so, how could I get benefit from this? Anyway thanks for your helpfulness! :-)

Comment: I am. I've explained why you might want to use it in my answer. If you need something clarifying I suggest you comment on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things going on here.

### Overheads

You're spending roughly half of the GPU time allocating and copying memory to and from the GPU. The CPU-GPU connection is a relatively slow link, and straight away halves your performance compared to the situation where the data starts and ends on the GPU and memory is allocated once. There are some things you can do to help here, such as moving the allocations outside of the loop, and overlapping the data transfer for one frame with the calculation of the next, but the pattern of copy->execute->copy rarely produces great runtimes unless the execution is quite complex.

### Kernel

Your kernel is expected to be memory bound. You are (ideally) moving 4 bytes/thread, with ~2 million threads (pixels) and a runtime of 853us you're getting about 10GB/s. The GTX 970's peak is 224GB/s. You're a long way off.

The problem here is that you're doing 8 bit transactions. The solution in this case would be to use shared memory. If you load data into shared memory in a high performance manner (eg. cast the pointers to int4s, making sure of alignment) at the start of the kernel, you can then read from that memory, then write back out with 32+ bits per thread. This means you're have to process multiple pixels a thread, but that's not a problem.

An alternative solution would be to find a library to do this operation. [NPP](https://developer.nvidia.com/npp), for example, covers a lot of image related tasks and may well be faster than hand-written code.

---

With a good memory access pattern I would expect this kernel to go >10x faster. Due to Amdahl's Law, you're going to be dominated by overhead once you've done this, so unless you can get rid of them the runtime is only going to be ~2x faster.